# how to flush memcached / spymemcached in java

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached, amazon-elasticache

I want to clear a hosted aws elasticache memcached instance.  I would like to do this programatically from java.

I have tried this without success:

```
 net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient client = new net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
 AddrUtil.getAddresses(endpoint1+":11211"+" "+ endpoint2+":11211"));

    client.flush();
```

How can I clear the cache programmatically in java?

Comment: So, what happens when you try your code? What happens when you try MemcachedClient(List<InetSocketAddress> addrs) constructor?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't clearing the cache? Have you tried retrieving a value after you call flush? I know that memcached only marks the keys as invalidated after you call flush, it doesnt actually perform the invalidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works. It was a permissions issue hitting the endpoint.